# What do the lowercase letters in Azure VM sizes mean?

Tags: azure

Azure offers various types of virtual machine sizes and they have uppercase letters (e.g. B, D, DC, E, F, etc). Some instance types also have lowercase letters (e.g. Da, Dd, Das, Ds, Ed, etc). Does that map to any specific functionality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Azure uses the following naming convention for its VM sizes:

`[Family] + [Sub-family]* + [# of vCPUs] + [Additive Features] + [Accelerator Type]* + [Version]`

- `Family`  Indicates the VM Family Series
- `*Sub-family` is used for specialized VM differentiations only
- `# of vCPUs` denotes the number of vCPUs of the VM
- `Additive Features`:
  One or more lower case letters denote additive features, such as:

  - a = AMD-based processor
  - d = disk (local temp disk is present); this is for newer Azure VMs, see Ddv4 and Ddsv4-series
  - h = hibernation capable
  - i = isolated size
  - l = low memory; a lower amount of memory than the memory intensive size
  - m = memory intensive; the most amount of memory in a particular size
  - t = tiny memory; the smallest amount of memory in a particular size
  - r = RDMA capable
  - s = Premium Storage capable, including possible use of Ultra SSD (Note: some newer sizes without the attribute of s can still support Premium Storage e.g. M128, M64, etc.)
- `*Accelerator Type` denotes the type of hardware accelerator in the specialized/GPU SKUs.
- `Version` denotes the version of the VM Family Series

**More information:**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/vm-naming-conventions

Comment: I first found out the pattern in the name that s is added for premium, then my senior programmer sent me to the docs link, and now I am here.